# passing appdelegate data to viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have the following method in my `AppDelegate.m`. I want the value of `deviceToken` in my `UIViewController`

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
viewController.tokenStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken];
 }
```

but when I display `NSLog(@"%@",tokenStr);` in `UIViewController` I'm getting `(NULL)`.
how can I get the value in my `UIViewController`?

Comment: How are you showing `ViewController`? add this just before pushing that object.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what do you mean ?

Comment: Can you please post the code which you have written to show ViewController on the screen. The above code just creates an object and does nothing else. There should something by which you are displaying it on the screen. You need to add this there.

Comment: I have `tokenStr` defined as a `@property` in `ViewController.h` and then I am just doing `NSLog(@"%@",tokenStr);` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: You should initialized `tokenStr` in before saving data
Try this
`viewController.tokenStr = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:deviceToken];`

Comment: @Sumanth, That is not needed. In fact he should have directly assigned as `viewController.tokenStr = deviceToken;` The problem here is he is not pushing this created instance to view, somewhere else he is having a different instance of this class which is what shown on the screen.

Comment: @ACB May be correct. He should assign the value before [navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];

Comment: I am sorry but I think you are not understanding the question. I just want to print (`NSLog`) the value of `deviceToken` in the `viewDidLoad` of my `viewController` just like I am printing it in my `AppDelegate`. I am not able to pass its value in the object that I have created in `ViewController.h`.

Comment: @AnkurArya. i have seen that method was in didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken. You are not pushing the `viewController` in that method. 
Where you are pushing or adding view to the window????
You should probably write that addSubView/Pushing next after `viewController.tokenStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken];` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `AppDelegate`, you can save the `deviceToken` value in `NSUserDefaults` like

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:deviceToken forKey:@"DeviceToken"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

and Retrieve that value from any View Controller using

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"DeviceToken"];
```

Comment: Where you are running it, either Device or iOS Simulator. If you are running it on Simulator, it'll always return NULL. Try it in Device.

Comment: I am running it on device. when I ran it for 1st time it was showing null after that it is showing the value, why is that?

Comment: What is data format of `deviceToken`?? Is it `String` or `NSArray`??Note that `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` formats will not save in `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: `deviceToken` is NSData. But as you are formatting with `NSString`. Did you try `self.tokenStr`.

Comment: Found it. If you are trying `ViewController` allocation in `appDelegate didFinishingLaunching` and again you are trying that in `didRegisterRemoteNotification`. this won't work. Because your appDelegate is first called, that time if you are trying to print `tokenStr` in your viewcontroller, it'll print NULL. after `didFinishLaunching` then only your `remoteNotification` in `appDelegate` is getting called. that time again you are allocating new `ViewController` instance and setting value. But you are already initialized your `tokenStr` to `ViewController` in `didFinishLaunching` method

Answer (score 1):

You can have a reference to AppDelegate with `[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate`.

It depends on your needs. Something like a token you really should save in NSUserDefaults, it was designed for saving user's credentials and tokens. But if you want to use all public properties and methods of AppDelegate in any viewController, you can use it's delegate.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
NSString *token = appDelegate.token;
```

Answer (score 1):

In AppDelegate.m class:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);

    NSString *device = [deviceToken description];
    device = [device stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    device = [device stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"My device is: %@", device);

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:device forKey:@"MyAppDeviceToken"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

In ViewController class, inside viewDidLoad method:

```
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *deviceToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MyAppDeviceToken"];
    NSLog(@"device token in controller: %@ ", deviceToken);
```

This is working perfectly in my device. Happy Coding !! :)